# Preceding command with timeout to ensure pod creation Before 'kubectl wait'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a command that can be executed in between this two instructions (which fails if the pod does not exist yet), and will wait for the pod to be created in the api-server within a specified timeout?

```
kubectl run mypod --image=nginx 
# Add a command which qait for 'kubectl get pod' to return mypod,
# so that 'kubectl wait' command will not fail
<wanted command>
kubectl wait pod/mypod --for=condition=Ready -l olm.catalogSource=argocd-catalog --timeout=120s
```

Comment: Can you check if the [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1219#issuecomment-1643441225) can be useful to you as a workaround.

Comment: Since the workaround provided to you seems to be useful.Can I provide the above comment as an answer for better community visibility ?

Comment: Yes please provide this comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1219#issuecomment-1643441225) link, you can use the below command as a workaround.

`kubectl wait` `timeout` argument is poorly documented and ill-suited to waiting on multiple resources.You can use `timeout` before the `kubectl wait` or `oc wait`. For example with a **timeout of max. 305s** (the timeout of the timeout command should be a **little larger** than the timeout of the kubectl command)

```
timeout $((300+5)) kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready --all pod --timeout=300s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create combined commands using `&&` (and) and `||` (or) between commands to implement how to run according to the different conditions.

The following combined command tries to run/create mypod. If it is created in a specific timeout, mypod will be created. After `||`, the `delete` command doesn't run, because the previous command works properly.

```
kubectl run mypod --image=nginx && kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pod/mypod --timeout=20s || kubectl delete pod mypod
```

Output:

```
pod/mypod created
pod/mypod condition met
```

**Worst case scenario:** The following command tries to run nginx2 (it won't work, due to the `ImagePullBackOff`). It first created the pod, but the pod is not ready, so it'll run the `delete` command after `||`.

```
kubectl run mypod --image=nginx2 && kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pod/mypod --timeout=20s || kubectl delete pod mypod
```

Output:

```
pod/mypod created
error: timed out waiting for the condition on pods/mypod
pod "mypod" deleted
```

You can create a similar combination with `get pods` instead of creating a pod.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want, I add some details in the question in order to make it more understandable.